# Whenever I try to open Hexxit it always crashes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-hexxit

This has always been a problem. Never have I ever had a time where I could get onto Hexxit; it always crashes! This is the report:

```
      Minecraft has crashed!      
      ----------------------      

Minecraft has stopped running because it encountered a problem; Failed to start game

A full error report has been saved to C:\Users\annabelle.cole\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\hexxit\crash-reports\crash-2014-11-22_11.34.49-client.txt - Please include a copy of that file (Not this screen!) if you report this crash to anyone; without it, they will not be able to help fix the crash :(



--- BEGIN ERROR REPORT fb414879 --------
Full report at:
C:\Users\annabelle.cole\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\hexxit\crash-reports\crash-2014-11-22_11.34.49-client.txt
Please show that file to Mojang, NOT just this screen!

Generated 22/11/14 11:34

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.5.2
    Operating System: Windows 7 (x86) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.7.0_45, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 42110536 bytes (40 MB) / 135794688 bytes (129 MB) up to 1037959168 bytes (989 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: FML and Forge are installed
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v7.51 FML v5.2.23.737 Minecraft Forge 7.8.1.737 68 mods loaded, 68 mods active
    mcp{7.51} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    FML{5.2.23.737} [Forge Mod Loader] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    Forge{7.8.1.737} [Minecraft Forge] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    CodeChickenCore{0.8.7.3} [CodeChicken Core] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    CoFHFramework{1.5.2.5} [CoFH Framework] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ImmibisMicroblocks{55.0.7} [Immibis's Microblocks] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    NotEnoughItems{1.5.2.28} [Not Enough Items] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    mod_bspkrsCore{v2.09(1.5.2)} [bspkrsCore] ([1.5.2]bspkrsCorev2.09.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    TreeCapitator{Forge 1.5.2.r14} [TreeCapitator] ([1.5.2]TreeCapitator.Forge.1.5.2.r14.Uni.CoreMod.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    CoFHCore{1.5.2.5} [CoFHCore] (CoFHCore-1.5.2.5.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    CoFHWorld{1.5.2.5} [CoFHWorld] (CoFHCore-1.5.2.5.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    CustomLAN{2.2} [Custom LAN Mod] (CustomPortForge.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ImmibisMicroblocksInstallCheck{55.0.7} [Immibis's Microblocks (Checks for incorrect installation, ignore this)] (immibis-microblocks-55.0.7.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    DamageIndicatorsMod{2.7.0.1} [Damage Indicators] (1.5.2 DamageIndicators v2.7.0.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    AsgardShield_Core{2.0.4} [AsgardShield] (1.5.2AsgardShield_Core_2.0.4Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ASAddon_Hallowed{2.0.0} [AS Addon- Hallowed] (1.5.2ASAddonHallowed_v2.0.0Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    HarkenScythe_Core{2.1.6} [HarkenScythe] (1.5.2HarkenScythe_v2.1.6Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ASAddon_HarkenScythe{2.0.0} [AS Addon- HarkenScythe] (1.5.2ASAddonHarkenScythe_v2.0.0Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ASAddon_NetherEnder{2.0.0} [AS Addon- Nether-Ender] (1.5.2ASAddonNetherEnder_v2.0.0Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ASAddon_ColorAPI{1.0.0} [ASAddon_ColorAPI] (1.5.2AsgardShield_Core_2.0.4Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Errored
    BetterStorage{0.6.2.23-hotfix2} [BetterStorage] ([1.5.2]BetterStorage_0.6.2.23-hotfix2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    mod_ArmorBarMod{0.7.1} [Armor Bar Mod] (ArmorBarv0.7.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    Artifice{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ArtificeCompat|Chisel{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Chisel] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ArtificeCompat|EE3{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: EE3] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ArtificeCompat|Forestry{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Forestry] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ArtificeCompat|MFR{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: MFR] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ArtificeCompat|Railcraft{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Railcraft] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ArtificeCompat|Vanilla{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Vanilla] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    Backpack{1.12.13} [Backpack] (backpack-1.12.13-1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    mod_BackTools{1.5.2v1} [mod_BackTools] (BackTools1.5.2v1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    BattleTowers{1.3.4} [Battle Towers] (BattleTowers_1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    BetterDungeons{1.8} [Better dungeons] (BetterDungeons.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    BiblioCraft{1.3.3} [BiblioCraft] (BiblioCraft[v1.3.3].zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    mod_BuffBarMod{0.7.1} [Buff Bar Mod] (BuffBarv0.7.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Errored
    ChestTransporter{1.1.6} [Chest Transporter] (chestTransporter_1.1.6_Universal.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Errored
    DimDoors{1.5.2R1.4.1RC1} [Dimensional Doors] (DimensionalDoors-1.5.2R1.4.1RC1-194.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    eplus{1.15.4} [Enchanting Plus] (EnchantingPlus-1.15.4.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ExtrabiomesXL{3.13.4} [ExtrabiomesXL] (ExtrabiomesXL-universal-1.5.2-3.13.4.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    hexxitgear{1.5.2R1.0} [Hexxit Gear] (HexxitGear-1.0-23.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ImmibisCore{55.1.6} [Immibis Core] (immibis-core-55.1.6.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    InfernalMobs{1.3.1} [Infernal Mobs] (InfernalMobs_1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    inventorytweaks{1.54b} [Inventory Tweaks] (InventoryTweaks-1.54b.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    MapWriter{2.0} [MapWriter] (mapwriter-2.0.5.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    Meteors{2.10.2} [Falling Meteors] (Meteors Mod V2.10.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    More Bows{1.5_v1} [More Bows mod] (More bows 1.5.2_2 Forge.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Errored
    Natura{2.1.5} [Natura] (Natura_1.5.2_2.1.5.1.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    Natura|CompatMineFactoryReloaded{0.1} [Natura compat: MFR] (Natura_1.5.2_2.1.5.1.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    NEIPlugins{1.0.9.3} [NEI Plugins] (NEIPlugins-1.0.9.3.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    LegendGear{1.5.2} [LegendGear] (NMcCoy-LegendGear-1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ObsidiPlates{1.5.0} [Obsidian Pressure Plates] (obsidiplates-1.5.2-universal-1.5.0.13.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    OffLawn{1.0} [offLawn] (OffLawn-1.5.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ProjectZulu|Core{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Core] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ProjectZulu|Blocks{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Block and Items] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ProjectZulu|Dungeon{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Mobs] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ProjectZulu|Mobs{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Mobs] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    ProjectZulu|World{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu World] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    QuantumCraft{1.01} [qCraft] (qCraft1.01.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    xreliquary{1.5.2} [Xeno's Reliquary] (Reliquary1.0.6d.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    rftl{1.0} [RottenFleshToLeather] (RottenFleshToLeather-1.5.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    AS_Ruins{10.3} [Ruins Spawning System] (Ruins_1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    secretroomsmod{4.6.0} [SecretRoomsMod] (SecretRoomsMod-universal-4.6.0.283.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    SoulShards{1.0.16} [Soul Shards] (SoulShards-1.0.36-universal-srg.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Errored
    TConstruct{1.5.2_1.4.3d7} [Tinkers' Construct] (TConstruct_1.5.2_1.4.3.final.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    TConstruct|CompatMineFactoryReloaded{0.1} [TConstruct Compat: MFR] (TConstruct_1.5.2_1.4.3.final.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    TwilightForest{1.18.1} [The Twilight Forest] (twilightforest-1.18.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    WildCaves3{0.4.2} [Wild Caves 3] (WildCaves3-0.4.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    chococraft{2.8.8} [Torojima's ChocoCraft] (zzzChococraft_2.8.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    LWJGL: 2.9.0
    OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 GL version 4.0.0 - Build 9.17.10.2932, Intel
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Texture Pack: Default
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown character '
```

Comment: To quote from the log you posted: "A full error report has been saved to C:\Users\annabelle.cole\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\hexxit\crash-reports\crash-2014-11-22_11.34.49-client.txt - Please include a copy of that file (Not this screen!) if you report this crash to anyone; without it, they will not be able to help fix the crash :("

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's modded Minecraft crash support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone overmodded to say the least. There might be way to fix this by adding ram. Those mods require at least 3-4 gb ram. So if you dont have that you might be screwed.

You can do this in the profile editor under Java settings (advanced). In JVM Arguments you will see that you can input how much ram you want Minecraft to be running on. In this box you fill in:

"-Xmx2048M -Xms2048M" for 2GB ram

"-Xmx4096M -Xms4096M" for 4GB ram

To add more, add 1024 to the numbers for an extra gigabyte.

eg, 4096 (4GB) + 1024 = 5120 (5GB)

You can also try to disable some mods and check where the errors lie.

It can be because you are using forge with a fairly old java version.Try to update to the latest runtime 7 java (forge still has trouble with runtime 8).

Comment: Hi Codermaster! I'm not that all technical so could you maybe explain in an easier manner that is teen friendly as I'm not that good with Java and stuff and minecraft is the only technical thing I do. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you actualy try then. make shure to back up then try some of the possibilities. I cant give mote details

Comment: Yes but where is the profile editor?

Comment: are u using the standard launcher

Answer (score 0):

Try Re-installing it. Same thing happened to me, I re-installed it, IT WORKED!